# Modifying default properties for HTML Annotation in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, html, annotation

How do I modify the default properties for the HTML annotation in QGIS 2.18?

For example, I don't want the red spot as a symbol or I want to change the frame width from 1.00 to 0.2.

Comment: Is there any way to select all the html annotation  balloons and change the default properties at once? Without clicking each one of these?

Comment: I don't think that option exists. There's nothing about annotations in Project Properties or Settings>Options. As far as I can tell, each annotation style has to be changed individually. I suggest making a [feature request](issues.qgis.org).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I found yesterday a possible solution. If you open the Project file with Notepad+++ editor you can find first the HTML annotation code , search for frameBorderWidth="0.29999999999999999"  and replace  with frameBorderWidth="1"  or whatever value want. You can do to the same for the colours , backgrounds , filepaths.

Comment: You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you open the Project file with Notepad+++ editor you can find  the HTML annotation code , search for frameBorderWidth="0.29999999999999999" or any other attribute and replace with frameBorderWidth="1" or whatever value want. You can do to the same for  colors , backgrounds , filepaths,symbols.